# Java spark submit with google secret manager no such method exception

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, google-secret-manager

I have a java spark program that uses google secret manager client libraries (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).
While doing spark submit I got following errors. Not sure what is going on here. Sounds like some dependency issue but could not find a solution yet. Any help is appreciated. "MyJar.jar" is an uber-jar that I created with maven.

> spark-submit --class com.myProgram.MyMain --master local[2]  --jars
> libs/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar target/MyJar.jar Exception in
> thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V
> at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.validateName(Metadata.java:754)
> at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.(Metadata.java:762)
> at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.(Metadata.java:671)
> at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.(Metadata.java:971)
> at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.(Metadata.java:966)
> at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:708)
> at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:704)
> at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:60)
> at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:321)
> at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1900(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:82)
> at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:240)
> at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
> at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:250)
> at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:228)
> at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:205)
> at com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.stub.GrpcSecretManagerServiceStub.create(GrpcSecretManagerServiceStub.java:248)
> at com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.stub.SecretManagerServiceStubSettings.createStub(SecretManagerServiceStubSettings.java:342)
> at com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient.(SecretManagerServiceClient.java:152)
> at com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient.create(SecretManagerServiceClient.java:133)
> at com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient.create(SecretManagerServiceClient.java:124)
> at com.myProgram.shared.AccessSecretVersion.getPrivateKey(AccessSecretVersion.java:12)
> at com.myProgram.MyMain.main(MyMain.java:33)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Comment: Changing the Dataproc image version for creating cluster to 2.0-debians from 1.5 solved my problem. This was used for spinning Spark cluster.https://github.com/googleapis/java-secretmanager/issues/651